# Variable 'n' cannot appear in the expressions below

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, fortran95

I want to do an iteration of the strain and stress change in rock mechanics, but am stuck on the errors:

> "real::STRAIN (1:N), SIGMA (1:N),DSIGMA (1:N),STRAIN (1:N)=0.0"

and

> "real,Dimension(6)::CEL(1:N,1:N)!stiffness matrix"

```
!program elastic_plastic

implicit none
!define all parameter
integer :: i = 1.0,j,K,M,N,inc
real::STRAIN (1:N), SIGMA (1:N),DSIGMA (1:N),DSTRAIN (1:N)=0.0
real,Dimension(6)::CEL(1:N,1:N)!stiffness matrix
real:: YOUNG, NU, COHESION !rock properties
real::ALPHA, KAPPA! cohesion and frictional angle
real::F !function
real::FRICTION_DEG, FRICTION_RAD !friction angle
real::VARJ2 ,VARI1 !stress invariants (I1 and J2)(MPa)
real:: LAMBDA,GMODU !lames constant and shear modulus
real::SIGMA_1,SIGMA_2,SIGMA_3 !principle stresses(MPa)
real::SHEAR_4,SHEAR_5,SHEAR_6 !shear stresses
real,parameter::DEG_2_RAD = 0.01745329


!INPUT
NU = 0.25
COHESION = 15 ! in MPa
YOUNG = 20 ! in GPa
FRICTION_DEG = 30.0d0
FRICTION_RAD = FRICTION_DEG *(DEG_2_RAD)

!perform calculations
KAPPA=6.*COHESION *cos(FRICTION_DEG*DEG_2_RAD)/(sqrt(3.)*(3.-sin(FRICTION_DEG*DEG_2_RAD)))
ALPHA=2.*sin(FRICTION_DEG*DEG_2_RAD)/(sqrt(3.)*(3.-sin(FRICTION_DEG*DEG_2_RAD)))
GMODU=YOUNG/2.*(1.+NU)
LAMBDA=NU*YOUNG/((1.+NU)*(1.-(2.*NU)))


!Set up elastic stiffness matrix (CEL)
CEL(1:N,1:N)=0.0
    CEL (1,1)= LAMBDA-(2.*GMODU)
    CEL (2,2)= LAMBDA-(2.*GMODU)
    CEL (3,3)= LAMBDA-(2.*GMODU)
    CEL (4,4)= 2.*GMODU
    CEL (5,5)= 2.*GMODU
    CEL (6,6)= 2.*GMODU


  DO
    inc = inc + 1
    DSTRAIN(1)=0.00002
    DSIGMA = matmul (CEL(1:N,1:N), DSTRAIN)
    SIGMA =SIGMA +DSIGMA
    STRAIN=STRAIN+DSTRAIN

     !calculate I1 AND J2
VARI1=SIGMA_1+SIGMA_2+SIGMA_3
VARJ2=1./6.*((SIGMA_1-SIGMA_2)**2+(SIGMA_2-SIGMA_3)**2+(SIGMA_3- SIGMA_1)**2+SHEAR_4**2+SHEAR_5**2+SHEAR_6**2)


!Yield function (Drucker-prager)
F= ALPHA*VARI1+(sqrt(VARJ2)-KAPPA)

IF (F.LE.0.0d0)then !Elastic step (exit)
    SIGMA =SIGMA
    STRAIN=STRAIN
    exit
    endif

    if (F.GT.0.0d0)then !Plastic step (continue)
goto 20
end if
20 continue
write(11,*)STRAIN,SIGMA,inc

END DO

end
```

Comment: Welcome, bu sure to take the [tour]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Very few people follow the Fortran 95 specific tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a variable mid-routine in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046719/how-to-declare-a-variable-mid-routine-in-fortran)

Comment: Or if you just intend for the array to be static: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31256569/3157076).

Comment: I had some suspicion, but I read only the answer and it spoke about some scalar so it didn't ring a bell. After re-tagging my dupehammer does not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can't statically define an array with a variable.  You must use a constant. 
 For example the following will work:

```
real::STRAIN (1:5), SIGMA (1:5),DSIGMA (1:5),DSTRAIN (1:5)=0.0
real,Dimension(6)::CEL(1:5,1:5)!stiffness matrix
```

If you don't know the size of the arrays at code time you can use the 'allocate' statement.  This is known as 'dynamic storage allocation'.  From ['Arrays and Parallel programming in Fortran 90/95'](http://kea.princeton.edu/ChE422/arrays.htm):

The way to declare an allocatable array is as follows:

```
integer Nparticles               ! number of particles
integer, parameter :: dim=3      ! dimensionality of space
...
real, allocatable :: charge(:)   ! defines an array containing the charge of 
                                 ! each particle 
integer, allocatable :: xyz(:,:) ! coordinates of each particle
```

Once the actual number of particles in the simulation has been read, we can allocate these arrays:

```
read(*,*) Nparticles
allocate (charge(Nparticles),xyz(dim,Nparticles))
```

Comment: The second declaration above still declares `CEL(1:5,1:5)` because the `Dimension(6)` part is overridden. This is a problem because `CEL(6,6)` is set later. The most fundamental problem is that `N` never got set. Had it been, the declarations that didn't compile could simply have been moved to a BLOCK construct afterwards, among many other possible solutions.

Comment: and when I run it just gives me a blank black screen

Comment: @francescalus Good point on the use of 'scalar'.  Thanks.  I made the correction.

Comment: sure you can use a symbol, it just needs to be declared a parameter, eg. `integer,parameter::n=6`